# Unable to use Custom Font

Tags: android, fonts, android-jetpack-compose, font-awesome

```
import androidx.compose.material3.Typography
import androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.Font
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontFamily
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import com.example.meditationui.R


val gothicA1 = FontFamily(
    listOf(
        Font(R.font.gothica1_regular, FontWeight.Normal),
        Font(R.font.gothica1_medium, FontWeight.Medium),
        Font(R.font.gothica1_semibold, FontWeight.SemiBold),
        Font(R.font.gothica1_bold, FontWeight.Bold),
        Font(R.font.gothica1_black, FontWeight.Black),
    )
)

// Set of Material typography styles to start with
val Typography = Typography(
    bodyLarge = TextStyle(
        fontFamily = FontFamily.Default,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
        fontSize = 16.sp,
        lineHeight = 24.sp,
        letterSpacing = 0.5.sp
    ),
    h1 = TextStyle(
        color = TextWhite,
        fontFamily = gothicA1,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
        fontSize = 22.sp
    )
)
```

h1 not detecting by Android Studio "Cannot find a parameter with this name: h1"

I am try to add custom font family to my project, but I am continuously facing this issue "Cannot find a parameter with this name: h1"

Comment: Android isn't html.  It doesn't use html tags.  H1 is not a concept of Android or of material design.  The actual constructor for Typography can be found at https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/wear/compose/material3/Typography

Comment: You might be going off of material 2 documentation.
Take a look at material 3's typography map https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/designsystems/material2-material3#typography

Answer (score 1):

`h1` is not supported by the Material's Typography class.
You can use `headlineLarge`, `headlineMedium` or `headlineSmall` instead. so something like:

```
val Typography1 = Typography(
    bodyLarge = TextStyle(
        fontFamily = FontFamily.Default,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
        fontSize = 16.sp,
        lineHeight = 24.sp,
        letterSpacing = 0.5.sp
    ),
    headlineMedium = TextStyle(
        color = TextWhite,
        fontFamily = gothicA1,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
        fontSize = 22.sp
    )
)
```